# Flask environment ignored in config.py

Tags: flask, config, environment, production

I'm trying to build a basic flask app for learning purposes. everything flows smoothly, but there's an issue I don't understand. in my run.py file, I have the following line:

```
app.config.from_object('config.prodConfig')
```

This loads config.py in the root, which contains the following code:

```
class Config:
SECRET_KEY = '1234567890'
STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'

class devConfig(Config):
FLASK_ENV = 'development'
DEBUG = True
TESTING = True

class prodConfig(Config):
FLASK_ENV = 'production'
DEBUG = False
TESTING = False
```

my understanding is that Config contains a few "default" settings. devConfig and prodConfig are based on Config, so will always contain those values, but each will have different env, debug and testing value. though I don't get any errors and debug seems to be activated, when I run my instance of Flask it tells me I'm running in production, regardless of what I do.

```
 * Serving Flask app "run" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
```

I'm not interested in setting the env variable in the terminal/environment, I know how to do that. what I'm interested in is why this doesn't work. after all, the FLASK_ENV directive is a valid one and it should load when instructed to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/) specifically warns against setting FLASK_ENV in code as any changes may not take effect if the app is already set up.

Comment: What’s the solution?

Comment: You want to set `ENV` not `FLASK_ENV`. Again, the documentation warns against doing this in code.

Answer (score 0):

With Chase's comment in mind, about not setting the FLASK_ENV in the app. Pass a `dict` of your configurations from your `config.py` and select the appropriate config based on the FLASK_ENV set outside your app, e.g. with a `.env` file.

config.py

```
class BaseConfig:
    ...

class DevConfig(BaseConfig):
    ...

class ProdConfig(BaseConfig):
    ...

configs = {"development": DevConfig, "production": ProdConfig}
```

app.py

```
import os
from flask import FLask
from config import configs
...
app.config.from_object(configs[os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV", "development")])
```